# Why is this kernel image not booting on QEMU

Tags: c, qemu

I was trying to boot a kernel image (created in `obj/kern/kernel.img` after executing `make`) on QEMU, following instructions given here:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-828-operating-system-engineering-fall-2012/labs/MIT6_828F12_lab1.pdf

but running `make qemu`, after `make`, doesn't give me the expected results. I only see the message 'Booting from hard disk' flickering continuously in the QEMU window. Ideally it should print out a bunch of logs as mentioned in the pdf.

The zipped project:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-828-operating-system-engineering-fall-2012/labs/lab1.tar.gz

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

The makefile is exactly the same as the one in the zip, I only made changes in this part:

```
...........................

# try to infer the correct QEMU
ifndef QEMU
QEMU := $(shell if which qemu > /dev/null; \
    then echo qemu; exit; \
    else \
    qemu=/usr/bin/qemu-system-i386; \
    if test -x $$qemu; then echo $$qemu; exit; fi; fi; \
    echo "***" 1>&2; \
    echo "*** Error: Couldn't find a working QEMU executable." 1>&2; \
    echo "*** Is the directory containing the qemu binary in your PATH" 1>&2; \
    echo "*** or have you tried setting the QEMU variable in conf/env.mk?" 1>&2; \
    echo "***" 1>&2; exit 1)
endif

...........................
```

the `qemu=` part to be precise

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the makefile.  Instead, change conf/env.mk as it suggests.  But first, verify that you actually have a working executable by invoking your qemu binary directly:

`qemu-system-i386 -machine help`

This should output a list of supported machines.  Then, figure out where the binary actually lives:

`which qemu-system-i386`

update conf/env.mk to use this path and start over from the beginning.